# Query parameter for page as normal WordPress "pretty" permalink

Tags: seo, wordpress, query-string, permalinks

I have a page that is generated dynamically based on a query parameter, which I wish to "mask" as a normal "pretty" permalink.

Right now I'm using:

```
https://example.com/dynamic-page/?parameter=xxx
```

and I wish to achieve this:

```
https://example.com/dynamic-page/xxx/
```

All this while using the following WP permalink structure:

```
/blog/%postname%/
```

So, currently, this is the WP part of my `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The `dynamic-page` does not have any children, so there is not already some permalink structure "below" it.  All this without messing with WP's standard permalink functionality.

Comment: How is this dynamic page implemented?  Is it a custom created `/dynamic-page/index.php` file or is it powered by a WordPress plugin?

Comment: It's a normal WP page whose contend depends on a query parameter, however, I have found what i needed. I'll post a response. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found what I was looking for. Here is what I'm using:

```
function add_query_vars($vars) {
    $vars[] = "parameter";
    return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
```

The above code adds the `parameter` query variable to the list WP looks for.

```
function add_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $newrules = array('dynamic-page/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=dynamic-page&parameter=$matches[1]');
    $rules = $newrules + $rules;
    return $rules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

The above does the actual URL rewrite, in the context provided by the original question.

More information can be found in this tutorial:

http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/